# SQL: age of oldest items

Tags: sql, oracle, select, max

I have following Oracle database. A certain ID can have an accepted status, but can continue in a failed status, and return back in an accepted status. This can happen X time, so it can be called a loop

```
ID       STATUS         TIME INSERT
------------------------------
1        Accepted       01:00:00
1        Failed         02:00:00
1        Accepted       02:30:00
2        Accepted       02:33:00
```

I want to calculate the age of the oldest item with an accepted status.
This means the result of SYSDATE - TIME INSERT

> As Result of this data I expect the 3d record time value, 02:30:00

I need to check for the youngest Time of every ID and than the oldest lifetime of all the youngest lifetimes of the ID's.
This looks quite complicated for me.

The workflow steps are:

1. the minimum time value of a specific id in the state Accepted
2. Step 1 for every id in the accepted state
3. the max value of all the min values I calculated in step 2.

At this moment I have following code

```
select min(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20000101','yyyymmdd')+(SYSDATE - dm1.time_insert),'hh24:mi:ss'))
from db dm1 
where dm1.status='accepted'
group by dm1.id;
```

This gives me a sequence of the min values of all records. But now I need the max value from all this min values, how do I do that?
Anyone who can solve this case?

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just find max(time_insert) and group by id. Take a look at sample query

```
    with src as (
select 1 as id, 'Accepted' as status, to_date('2015-05-05 01:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as time_insert from dual
union all
select 1 as id, 'Failed' as status, to_date('2015-05-05 02:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as time_insert from dual
union all 
select 1 as id, 'Accepted' as status, to_date('2015-05-05 02:30:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as time_insert from dual
union all
select 2 as id, 'Accepted' as status, to_date('2015-05-05 02:33:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as time_insert from dual)

select id, max(time_insert) as time_insert, max(sysdate - time_insert) as lifetime_max, min(sysdate - time_insert) as liftime_min from src 
where status ='Accepted'
group by id
```

> Edit: Is this what you want to achieve:

```
with src as (
select 1 as id, 'Accepted' as status, to_date('2015-05-05 01:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as time_insert from dual
union all
select 1 as id, 'Failed' as status, to_date('2015-05-05 02:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as time_insert from dual
union all 
select 1 as id, 'Accepted' as status, to_date('2015-05-05 02:30:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as time_insert from dual
union all
select 2 as id, 'Accepted' as status, to_date('2015-05-05 02:33:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as time_insert from dual)
, src2 as (
select max(time_insert) as time_insert, max(sysdate - time_insert) as lifetime_max, min(sysdate - time_insert) as lifetime_min from src 
where status ='Accepted')
select max(lifetime_min) from src2
```

Comment: That's not what I want to achieve. I get a sequence of every id, I want the max value of all id's.

Comment: Updated the answer. Added additional query. Please let me know if this is what you want to acheive.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this will help you:

```
-- this will give you the minimum date of all id's
select * from tab1 where TIME_INSERT  in (select min(TIME_INSERT) from tab1 )and STATUS ='Accepted'
```

```
-- this will give you the minimum date of a specefique id 
select * from tab1 where TIME_INSERT  in (select min(TIME_INSERT) from tab1 )
and STATUS ='Accepted' and ID =1
```

check this

```
select id, TIME_INSERT from
 (select TIME_INSERT, ID , min(TIME_INSERT) over (partition by ID) maxid from tab1) 
where TIME_INSERT = maxid and TIME_INSERT in(select max(TIME_INSERT) from tab1) group by ID,TIME_INSERT
```

Comment: that's a good beginning, now I need the max value of all the min id's :)

Comment: I want: 1. the minimum time value of a specific id in the state Accepted, 2. I want this minimum value calculation of every id, 3. I want the max value of all these minimum values.

Answer (score 1):

this will do it.

```
SELECT id,
       min(time_insert),
       max(time_insert)
FROM   
       your_table t1
WHERE  
       status = 'Accepted' 
AND    time_insert > (
          SELECT
                  nvl(max(time_insert), to_date('01-JAN-1970', 'DD-MON-YYYY'))
          FROM 
                  your_table
          WHERE 
                  status = 'Failed'
          AND     id = t1.id
       )
GROUP BY id
```